# An app installed from google play does not show nowhere (Home Screen, Drawer, and Widgets)

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I created open testing for my app on play store.
Installed the app, but the app does not appear nowhere on my phone, hence cannot be opened.

It's not on Home Screen, Drawer, and Widgets.
But in the app list of the setting app, it appear as installed app.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngwvY.jpg)

On google play, there is only "uninstall" button, and no "open app" button.

I've been struggling for weeks...
What could be causing this?
(Not sure if this is right place to ask. If this isn't, let me know. I'll delete this post)

Comment: Show your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with your manifest :

Please Check Carefully ,in your manifest you should have tools, Application name ,label ,icon . icon must need to be valid and in the application export should be true . see the bellow example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.esa"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application android:label="esa" android:name="${applicationName}" android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon" tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I had no **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"**, **android:exported="true"** and **tools:replace="android:icon"** so added. But still seems not working after flutter clean -> flutter run..

Answer (score -2):

Re-install the Application sometimes it's not downloaded all files.

Comment: I tried several times. but didn't work..

Comment: This answer is better off as a comment.